# jshint erros while including js in custom MEAN.IO package

Tags: jquery, openlayers, jshint, mean.io

I am trying to include a js file that I have created from scratch. This javascript needs other js files like OpenLayers and jQuery (which I am also importing by aggregating it) however the jsHint is making my project fail stating that $ is undefined or ol is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to tell jshint how to behave. Add a file named `.jshintrc` in your project root with the following:

```
{
  "jquery": true
}
```

This should resolve your $ error. Any other warnings about undefined globals you can solve with the predef option, like so:

```
{
  "jquery": true,
  "predef": [
    "requirejs", "Backbone", "your_global_here"
  ]
}
```

There are tons of other options you can put in the jshintrc: http://jshint.com/docs/options/

Comment: hi sir, is there a way for jshint to see those variable instead of using predef? thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by making jshint "see" those variables, could you elaborate on that?